# Setting the width of a TextField filter in a Vaadin Grid column header to the width of the column content

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am using a Vaadin Grid and in a column header I put a TextField filter field to filter the content. The header row is created using grid.appendHeaderRow() and the TextField is added to the header row as follows:

```
filteringHeader = grid.appendHeaderRow();
filteringHeader.getCell(column).setComponent(filterTextField);
```

The column itself has been set to autosize and to have no flexgrow

```
column.setAutoWidth(true).setFlexGrow(0);
```

Without the filterHeader the column automatically sizes the width to the content in the column, but with the filterHeader the column width expands to the default width of a TextField. Setting the width of the TextField to 100% allows it to expand to the width of the column, but it can never be narrower than the default TextField width.

My question is how do I set the TextField to be the same size as the autosized column, even for cases where the content is narrower than the default FextField width, and where I do not know the minimum width in px?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, I know, but...have you tried setting the max width of the text field?

Answer (score 0):

```
    FlexLayout filterContainer = new FlexLayout(filterTextField);
    filterTextField.setWidth("0px");
    flexLayout.setFlexGrow(1.0, filterTextField);
    filteringHeader.getCell(column).setComponent(filterTextField);
```

I also use:

```
column.setClassNameGenerator(o -> "text-overflow-clip")
```

frontend/themes/[theme]/components/vaadin-grid.css

```
[part~='body-cell'].text-overflow-clip ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Summary:
When using:

```
grid.addColumn().setFlexGrow(0).setAutoWidth(true).setClassNameGenerator(o -> "text-overflow-clip")
```

column will fit contents for TextField/ComboBox/MultiSelectComboBox filters